# Burn many audio file types to CD while still keeping quality?

Tags: mp3, compact-disc, flac, ape

I have a bunch of many MP3, FLAC, APE and WAV files and I want to burn them to a single CD which will be played on a car CD player, while still keeping their quality at highest level. How can I do this?

Player supports MP3, WMA and WAV only.

Comment: What file types does your car DVD player support?

Comment: I think they are MP3, WMA and WAV only. Other loss-less types may not be played. And the total size of these files is more than 3GB.

Comment: Don't you think you should be *sure* of what file types your car DVD player can handle, before you ask for software that would be converting what you have to what you need?  And for that matter, what is the maximum bitrate your car DVD player can handle?  Maybe including the car DVD player make and model would be helpful?  Otherwise, the answer to your question "how can I do this?" is "use software to convert them".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert the Wave, Flac and APE to MP3 (256 CBR), you can leave the other MP3s alone since converting to another bit rate is not recommended. 320CBR has some issues with some players, 256 is safe and sounds just as good.

Burn the MP3 files to CD as Data, you can create a folder structure to sort MP3's or just burn all the files to CD without folders, your choice.

Be sure to tag the MP3's correctly as all car players use these tags for display and navigation purposes.

Wave sounds better but they take up too much room on a CD, so you get a lot less songs per dvd.

Comment: Actually it's not my car. I have checked its specification and too bad that it supports CD playing only. I will convert these files to MP3 and burn them. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You can get more songs on a CD if you use 192(VBR), you can experiment to see if they sound as good.